# What's the best way to cancel a long operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, backgroundworker

I have run into a problem that I'm not sure how to resolve. I have a method that contains a call from a service that populates a data table such as:

```
private void GetCases()
{
    try
    {
        //Setup our criteria
        Web_search_criteria myCriteria = new Web_search_criteria()
        {
            Keynum = 9, //Use Opening Date Key
            Range_start = "20100101", //01-01-2010
            Range_end = "20121223" //12-23-2013
        };


        //The myCases object is a datatable that is populated from the GetCasesDT() call.
        int status = db.server.GetCasesDT(myCriteria, ref myCases);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Unable to get data: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, there isn't a way for me to grab just a few cases at a time - it just grabs it all.

Right now, I have this method being called in a BackgroundWorker's DoWork event, and I display another form with a marquee progress bar on it so the user will know that the system is actually doing something. On that form, I have a Cancel button that I subscribe to. Here is the code that does that:

```
    backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker() 
    { 
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
        WorkerReportsProgress = true
    };

    //DoWork Event
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;

    //Show the progress bar with subscription to event
    pb.btnCancel.Click += this.CancelBW;
    pb.Show();

    //Run the backgroundworker
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    //Don't lock up the application
    while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

I have tried to cancel the BackgroundWorker in the CancelBW event by using CancelAsync(), but then I read more and realize that doesn't work and would only work if I could break up that initial call so the BackgroundWorker could check on progress.

I have thought about using Thread instead of a BackgroundWorker, but have read that Aborting a thread will cause kittens to spontaneously combust.

So, what's the best way for me to handle this in which a user could cancel a long process?

Comment: +1 for spontaneous combustion of kittens.  (Now there's a line I never expected to put on the internet.)

Comment: What version of .NET/C# are you using? If .NET 4.0/4.5 you could try using tasks which include support for cancellation tokens.

Comment: @ledbutter Thanks for the suggestion. I am using 4.0, so I will take a look at the Tasks class to see how that works.

Comment: Just food for thought: This may be against the goal of your application, and will definitely change user experience, but you could also consider paging. Where if they give a date range greater than XX days, you only request 30days and have a More or Next button to get more data. *Or* could automatically chain the 30day requests upon completion, so you're displaying data immediately as you ramp up to the full 3years worth of data.  Not an answer to your question, but another way to look at the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fundamental way to properly cancel this operation.  It's not CPU bound work, it's network bound work.  You sent the request, you can't exactly pluck that request from the internet.  All you can really do is have your code continue executing when your cancel conditions are met instead of waiting around for the operation to finish.

One major issue with your application is the busyloop that you have pumping the message queue:

```
while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

This is generally a bad idea, and is a practice that should be avoided.  The idea of using a `BackgroundWorker` in the first place is for it to be asynchronous; you shouldn't be trying to block the current method until the BGW finishes.

While there are ways of incorporating a BGW into this; this particular case it probably easier to solve using the Task Parallel Library.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

pb.btnCancel.Click += (s, e) => cts.Cancel();
pb.Show();

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetCases())
    .ContinueWith(t => t.Result, cts.Token)
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        //TODO do whatever you want after the operation finishes or is cancelled;
        //use t.IsCanceled to see if it was canceled or not.
    });
```

(I'd also suggest refactoring `GetCases` so that it returns the `DataTable` that it gets from the DB, rather than modifying an instance field.  You can then access it through the Task's `Result`.

Comment: @user1949119 What problems are you running into?  Without knowing what they are, there's no way for me to say.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and the example code. I'm running into a problem with t.Result though - 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1949119 See my last paragraph.  I'm proposing that `GetCases` should be returning a result, which means the task will have a result.  if you don't do that, it doesn't have a result, and so you'd need to not use it.  While you *could* just take out the use of the result, the preferred solution is to ensure that the task has a result by modifying `GetCases`.

Comment: Also, the TPL has support for async and await in C# 5, which really helps in cleaning up the code

Comment: @user1949119 You're likely blocking the UI thread from somewhere.  It's not in the code that you've shown, it's likely somewhere else.  You're blocking at some time where you should be performing an operation asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy - thanks so much for all of your help! Working great now!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to abort threads (which, indeed, will cause the world to collapse and kittens to combust), the only sane way to end a thread is granularizing the work inside it and perform frequent checks for cancellation tokens (in whichever form you prefer them: built in [for the TPL], messages, locked variables, semaphores, or whatever) and end the thread "cleanly".